# WordPress: How to append to title via functions.php for auto-posting plugin

Tags: wordpress, function, plugins, filter

### What I've got so far

I've finally got the `functions.php` plugin to append a string to custom post titles of a certain post type with this function:

```
function append_album_review_to_title( $title ) {
    global $post;
    $text = 'Album Review: ';

    if ( get_post_type( $post->ID ) == 'album_review' && in_the_loop() ){
        return $text . $title;
    }
    else {
        return $title;
    }
}
if(function_exists('add_filter')) {
    add_filter('the_title', 'append_album_review_to_title');
}
```

and though it does *almost* everything I need it to, it still doesn't append the string to titles as they are posted via auto-posting plugins.

### The problem

The plugin I am using is **NextScripts: Social Networks Auto Poster** and everywhere I can see the title, the desired string is appended but when this plugin auto-posts, the string is not appended.

### The Question

How can I change my function to also apply to the titles as they are output by auto-posting plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

```
function append_album_review_to_title( $title, $id = NULL ) {
    if ($id) {
        if ( get_post_type( $id ) == 'album_review' ){
            return 'Album Review: ' . $title;
        } else {
            return $title;
        }
    } else {
        return 'Album Review: ' . $title;
    };
}
add_filter('the_title', 'append_album_review_to_title', 10, 2);
```

#### Explanation

First trying this:

```
function append_album_review_to_title( $title, $id ) {
    if ( get_post_type( $id ) == 'album_review' ){
        return 'Album Review: ' . $title;
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}
add_filter('the_title', 'append_album_review_to_title', 10, 2);
```

I noticed that on the backend, the social sharing plugin I am using to auto-share posts would return warnings like `missing parameter 2` and `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object...`, and so it occurred to me that unlike the front end (nav menu and the loop), in the backend, apparently an `$id` is not being passed to `the_title` and so I can use this as a conditional.

Checking for `$id` will, for my purposes, tell me that if it is `true`, we are on front end, if it is `false`, then we are at backend post view.

This code accomplishes what I need (ie, modify post title in the loop, do NOT modify nav menu items, and modify `the_title` for use by a backend social sharing plugin):